# Unsupported encoding command ansicpg949

Tags: mpxj

using `mpxj~, .mpp` file upload.

```
net.sf.mpxj.mpp.MPPReader called -> read(InputStream is)
```

Error code:

```
ProjectReader reader = new MPPReader ();
ProjectFile project;

try {
project = reader.read(uploadFile.getInputStream());
```

**Error file :** [rtfparserkit](https://github.com/joniles/rtfparserkit/files/108227/error.zip)

**mpxj bug ticket :** http://sourceforge.net/p/mpxj/bugs/289/

Help~

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported encoding command ansicpg949
at com.rtfparserkit.parser.standard.StandardRtfParser.processEncoding(StandardRtfParser.java:349)
at com.rtfparserkit.parser.standard.StandardRtfParser.processCommand(StandardRtfParser.java:150)
at com.rtfparserkit.parser.raw.RawRtfParser.handleCommand(RawRtfParser.java:278)
at com.rtfparserkit.parser.raw.RawRtfParser.handleCommand(RawRtfParser.java:241)
at com.rtfparserkit.parser.raw.RawRtfParser.parse(RawRtfParser.java:87)
at com.rtfparserkit.parser.standard.StandardRtfParser.parse(StandardRtfParser.java:50)
at com.rtfparserkit.converter.text.AbstractTextConverter.convert(AbstractTextConverter.java:41)
at com.rtfparserkit.converter.text.StringTextConverter.convert(StringTextConverter.java:34)
at net.sf.mpxj.common.RtfHelper.strip(RtfHelper.java:61)
at net.sf.mpxj.mpp.MPP14Reader.processTaskData(MPP14Reader.java:1513)
at net.sf.mpxj.mpp.MPP14Reader.process(MPP14Reader.java:102)
at net.sf.mpxj.mpp.MPPReader.read(MPPReader.java:136)
at net.sf.mpxj.mpp.MPPReader.read(MPPReader.java:79)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue will be fixed in the next version of MPXJ (5.1.19 or later)

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking forward to the next version.